# Line chart lines with same value are overlapping

Tags: swift, charts, linechart

I am using [danielgindi
/
Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for creating line chart. When Line chart data has same values, only the last drawn line showing. Other lines are hidden behind the last drawn line. Is there any way to show all lines.

image: 'fff' and 'User B' is hidden behind 'User C', they all have number of activities equal to zero

[image]

**Line chart initialisation**

```
 func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
        
        lblXAxis.text = "Days"
        lblYAxis.text = "Number of Activities"
        lblYAxis.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
        
        self.roundAllCorners(radius: 6)
        
        let valFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        valFormatter.numberStyle = .none
        valFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        viewProgressLineChart.leftAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(formatter: valFormatter)
        viewProgressLineChart.leftAxis.granularity = 1
        viewProgressLineChart.xAxis.granularity = 1
        viewProgressLineChart.xAxis.labelCount = 11
        viewProgressLineChart.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = false
        viewProgressLineChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        viewProgressLineChart.chartDescription?.text = ""
        viewProgressLineChart.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.onPrimary
        viewProgressLineChart.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.onPrimary
        viewProgressLineChart.rightAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.onPrimary
        viewProgressLineChart.clipValuesToContentEnabled = true
        viewProgressLineChart.legend.enabled = false
        viewProgressLineChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        viewProgressLineChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.8)
        
    }
```

**This is how data is given to line chart,**

```
func updateGraph(users: [User]){
 let data = LineChartData()
        for (index,user) in users.enumerated(){
            let userColor = UIColor.selectedColors[index]
            
            userAndStatusColorArray.append(UserAndStatusColor(name: user.name ?? "user", color: userColor))
            
            var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
            
            if user.progress != nil{
                for progress in user.progress!{
                    let chartData = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(progress.day), y: Double(progress.activitiesCompleted!))
                    lineChartEntry.append(chartData)
                }
                
                let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry)
                chartDataSet.colors = [userColor]
                chartDataSet.circleColors = [userColor]
                chartDataSet.circleRadius = 3
                chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
                data.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
            }
        }
        viewPODProgressLineChart.viewProgressLineChart.data = data
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your chart initialization code?

Comment: @LucaPizzini Question updated.